# When I am preparing a commit using GIT, how can I set it up so that it diffs against an earlier version rather than the previous version?

Tags: git

I commit often. When I am preparing a commit (using [SourceTree](https://www.sourcetreeapp.com/)), I want to see the diff compared to the first pull from the main branch, not the last commit I made, which is usually incomplete and non-functional. I want to see my changes against the original version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SourceTree you can diff any 2 points in history just by Cmd-clicking to select two commit lines in the log view.

Answer (score 3):

Difference between head and any commit:

git diff commit_id HEAD